# Why cannot I change my dataframe using if condition in a for loop?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe train_morgan which is larger and I have a train_df which is smaller. I want to change 'TargetClass' in train_morgan using condition but it remains the same after loop. 'SpType' is a column based on which values target column should be changed. What shall I do?
Thanks

```
for i in range(len(train_df)):
    a = train_morgan[train_morgan['SpType'] == train_df['SpType'][i]]['TargetClass'].mean()
    b = train_df.iloc[i, -1]
    if a != b:
        train_morgan.loc[train_morgan['SpType'] == train_df['SpType'][i], 'TargetClass'] = b
```

I tried to understand why it remains the same and I thought to copy the dataset but vainly.

Comment: Can you put some sample data in the question to help us understand what you're working with?

Comment: https://www.kaggle.com/datasets/vinesmsuic/star-categorization-giants-and-dwarfs?select=Star39552_balanced.csv

Comment: I think the main question is why dataframe can't be changed in the loop. Because as I work in colab and change only one value out of the loop, dataset becomes different.
When I want to print the dataframe after this code, I get the original data. How is it possible?

Comment: Can you be more specific with the data.  I don't know what you have as train_norgan or train_df.  putting the first 5 rows of both would help.  Also, an example of what you want your output to look like as this code is a bit hard to follow